# Snowflake - How to organize patient overlap across product categories

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to segment out customer data based on the categories they've purchased.

We have a customerID, and all the different categories they've purchased from in the past.

| CustomerID | ProductCategory |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Biking |
| 122 | Running |
| 1234 | Swimming |
| 1235 | Golfing |

'''
Ideally, I want my end result to group by product category and order by highest distinct pt count.
However, in doing so, I want to capture a venn diagram of customer overlap. There are 39 product categories and a null category. A patient can have all 40 options.

The first approach I've tried is:

```
WITH Customers AS (
    select distinct
      listagg( distinct productcategory, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY productcategory) as  productcategory_list
      , customer_id
      from table) 
select productcategory_list
   , count( distinct customer_id) as cust_Count  
from patients
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

The issue I'm having with the above code is that it displays the specific combinations in order, when what I'm looking for is to display the highest counts across categories and combinations.
So for example, I would hope for results like:

| ProductCategory | Distinct CustCount |
| --- | --- |
| Biking | 23,000 |
| Running | 17,000 |
| Swimmming | 15,000 |
| Biking, Running | 14,500 |

With the ideal output above, I would want the customers on lines 4 to be included in lines 1 and lines 2, rather than only being counted once.

Any coding suggested would be appreciated. I attempted to apply

```
Case WHEN PRODUCTCATEGORY = 'Swimming' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PC_Swimming
```

, but I couldn't think of a way to efficiently sum the totals and maintain the relationship.

Comment: You are saying there are 40 different categories (a,b,c,d,e...). Then you want to count the # of people for each possible combination? (As in [a], [a,b], [a,c], [a,b,c], [a,b,d]...). That's a fun experiment, but we would need to generate more than a trillion combinations with 40 categories.

Comment: using bitmaps of the customers id's would allow counting distinct count per combo, but also allow for joining those together, to get the higher groupings (aka the hierarchical discount customer example from Summit)

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-bitmaps-for-distinct-counts.html